# form_alter and #element_validate inside .module file

Tags: forms, 8

Inside my `.module` file, I have created a hook for alter `register_form` and add a *password* field with a custom field-validation:

```
function xenforo_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form['password'] = array(
    '#type' => 'password_confirm',
    '#size' => 25,
    '#required' => true,
    '#element_validate' => array('check_password'),
    );
}
function check_password($element, &$form_state) {
  if ($element['#value'] != 'test') {
    form_error($element, t('Error: TEST'));
  }
}
```

I use #element_validate, and when I submit my form with a bad value `$element['#value'] != 'test'`, I don't have an error and the registration is completed, why `#element_validate` don't work here please ?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I have find a solution:

```
  function xenforo_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['password'] = array(
      '#type' => 'password_confirm',
      '#size' => 25,
      '#required' => true,
      '#attributes' => array('autocomplete' => 'off'),
      //'#element_validate' => array('check_password'),
      '#process' => array('processPasswordConfirm'),
    );
  }

  function processPasswordConfirm(&$element, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, &$complete_form) {
    $element['pass1'] =  array(
      '#type' => 'password',
      '#title' => t('Password'),
      '#value' => empty($element['#value']) ? NULL : $element['#value']['pass1'],
      '#required' => $element['#required'],
      '#attributes' => array('class' => array('password-field')),
    );
    $element['pass2'] =  array(
      '#type' => 'password',
      '#title' => t('Confirm password'),
      '#value' => empty($element['#value']) ? NULL : $element['#value']['pass2'],
      '#required' => $element['#required'],
      '#attributes' => array('class' => array('password-confirm')),
    );
    $element['#element_validate'] = array('check_password');
    $element['#tree'] = TRUE;

    return $element;
  }

  function check_password($element, &$form_state) {
    if ($element['#value'] != 'test') {
      //form_error($element, t('Error: TEST'));
    }
  }
```

But I have again the error with form_error() and password as displayed as two field without [image]

Comment: Probably because password_confirm isn't a single element, it gets converted into two separate fields in a process callback, and doesn't apply the `#element_validate` to either of those because it can't reconcile which one you were referring to

Comment: Have you a solution please ? I have try with password only, but I need two fields and with "password" and not "password_confirm" I have an another error: **form_error($element, t('Error: TEST'));**, form_error is not available on .module file ? I search a solution for have password fields and get a plainpassword inside my validate() function and set my own encryption and push the password inside the database by myself.

Answer (score 0):

As per [@Clive comment](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/145819/form-alter-and-element-validate-inside-module-file#comment175174_145819), it's probably because `password_confirm` isn't a single element, it gets converted into two separate fields in a process callback, and doesn't apply the `#element_validate` to either of those because it can't reconcile which one you were referring to.